# why dont we need feature scaling in multiple linear regression

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

I am currently learning ML
and I notice that in multiple linear regression we don't need scaling for our independent variable
and I didn't know why?

Comment: This site is not geared to deal with this type of question. Can you reframe your question into a coding issue?

Comment: Although I answered, I can see @Display name's point. Maybe we should move this to https://stats.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions; non-coding questions about machine learning theory & methodology are off-topic here, and should be posted at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead. Please notice the **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML/stats theory & methodology.

Answer (score 3):

Whether feature scaling is useful or not depends on the training algorithm you are using.

For example, to find the best parameter values of a linear regression model, there is a closed-form solution, called the Normal Equation. If your implementation makes use of that equation, there is no stepwise optimization process, so feature scaling is not necessary.

However, you could also find the best parameter values with a gradient descent algorithm. This could be a better choice in terms of speed if you have many training instances. If you use gradient descent, feature scaling is recommended, because otherwise the algorithm might take much longer to converge.